# Displaying Precisely Scaled Images With URP Decal Projector

Tags: unity, unity-urp, decal-system

I am using Unity's URP Decal Projector to display an oval shaped blob shadow texture.

The image's dimensions are 227 x 70. However, when I use it as a base map for my Shader Graphs/Decal material, it just displays as a small circle.
The only scaling options I see are Width and Height, which work similar to a Transform's X & Y scale.
These can be adjusted to "estimate" the correct size, but it seems very far from precise.

Is there anyway that I can preserve the texture's aspect ratio/native size so that I can display it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textures are mapped in normalized coordinates, so 1.0 is the far side of the texture, no matter whether it's 2 pixels wide or 2000.

But you van easily achieve an exact aspect ratio by scaling the with:height values to have the same 227:70 ratio as your base map.

Any multiple of 227/70 = 3.2428571428571:1.0 will work.

Comment: Just a typo on my part when I plugged it into my calculator, I'm guessing. Width divided by height is the calculation you want here.